# ERROR: gyp_chromium returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: linux, centos, chromium

I'm trying to checkout the android version of [chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/) on [CentOS 2.6.18](http://www.centos.org/) 
I'm following the official instructions provided in this [link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions)

unfortunately, when i run

```
gclient runhooks
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Command /usr/local/bin/python src/build/gyp_chromium returned
>   non-zero exit status 1 in /root

Here is the full output:

```
[root@centos build]# gclient runhooks
    Running depot tools as root is sad.

    ________ running '/usr/local/bin/python src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py --no-arm-trusted --keep' in '/root'
    /root/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/toolchain_linux_x86.tar.bz2 is already up to date.
    linux_x86: already up to date.
    /root/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/naclsdk_linux_x86.tgz is already up to date.
    linux_x86_newlib: already up to date.
    /root/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/naclsdk_pnacl_linux_x86.tgz is already up to date.
    pnacl_linux_x86: already up to date.
    /root/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/naclsdk_pnacl_translator.tgz is already up to date.
    pnacl_translator: already up to date.

    ________ running '/usr/local/bin/python src/build/linux/install-arm-sysroot.py --linux-only' in '/root'

    ________ running '/usr/local/bin/python src/chrome/installer/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-debian.wheezy.sysroot.py --linux-only --arch=amd64' in '/root'

    ________ running '/usr/local/bin/python src/chrome/installer/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-debian.wheezy.sysroot.py --linux-only --arch=i386' in '/root'

    ________ running '/usr/local/bin/python src/tools/clang/scripts/update.py --mac-only' in '/root'

    ________ running '/usr/local/bin/python src/build/win/setup_cygwin_mount.py --win-only' in '/root'

    ________ running '/usr/local/bin/python src/build/util/lastchange.py -o src/build/util/LASTCHANGE' in '/root'

    ________ running '/usr/local/bin/python src/build/util/lastchange.py -s src/third_party/WebKit -o src/build/util/LASTCHANGE.blink' in '/root'

    ________ running '/usr/local/bin/python src/build/gyp_chromium' in '/root'
    Updating projects from gyp files...
    gyp: Call to '../build/linux/python_arch.sh /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0' returned exit status 1. while trying to load /root/src/build/all.gyp

    Error: Command /usr/local/bin/python src/build/gyp_chromium returned non-zero exit status 1 in /root
```

**How to solve this to continue building steps ?**

Comment: @AshrafBahir I also face this problem did you solve this issue

Comment: Unfortunately we didn't find any solution for this, so we gave up the whole project :( ... If you find one, send it :(

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit the file common.gypi in trunk/build to change system_libdr% to be lib64, not lib. There's probably some way to pass that into gclient, but I couldn't figure out how. On Centos 64bit, the libs live in /usr/lib64.

Answer (score 0):

You can override system_libdir with:

```
$ export GYP_DEFINES=system_libdir=lib64
```

I filed a [Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=272740) to address this.

Comment: I think you sent a wrong url. Kindly check the url which you sent, because this is the link of my reported bug to chromium, so I think you meant another url where you filled a bug for it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the python version installed on your system ?

I had the same issue and it was simply because my system provides python 2.7 instead of 2.6.

If that is also your case, you can try running it again with:

```
GYP_DEFINES=python_ver=2.7
```